# Replacing JavaScript context this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I read a few articles about scope and context but I still have a question, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5L2qy092/7/) is my JSFiddle. I want to change my functions to arrow functions and replace "this" keyword by their actual window value.

This is my current code.

```
$(this).on('click', "i.fa.fa-minus-square", function(e) {
  table.row( $(this).closest('tr') ).remove().draw();
});
```

This is what I have tried but it doesn't seem to work.

```
 "initComplete": (oSettings) => {
    $(".fa.fa-minus-square").on('click', "i.fa.fa-minus-square", (e)=> {
       table.row( $(".fa.fa-minus-square").closest('tr') ).remove().draw();
    });
  }
```

Any ideas would be very appreciated.

Comment: You don't seem to be using `this` in the code you posted.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv check the JSFiddle I posted I'm using it there the code sample I posted is what I have tried to change

Comment: Why not just use `window` instead of `this`? By the way: Where do you use `this` in your code?

Comment: Update your question with the actual code.  Don't force us to go to an off site share site.  You can type Ctrl+M or click the `<>` button to make an onsite working snippet.

Comment: Your maybe after `event.target`.  So in your example,  `e.target`, should give you what `this` would give you using `function ()`

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv does my question make more sense now?

Comment: @David check my updated question, it should make more sense

Comment: `$(".fa.fa-minus-square").on('click', "i.fa.fa-minus-square"` looks like the code is trying to delegate bind on itself.  Which doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Taplar does it look better now? also how can I replace it then without using this

Comment: You are creating a table on `#example` and `"initComplete"` is called with `this` being bound to the table element so logically you'd replace your `$(this)` with `$('#example')` ?

Comment: @sbattoh I don't see any update to the question.

Comment: @apokryfos I don't know what I was thinking, it worked, thank you so much!!!

Comment: @Taplar how about now? My question has already been answered. Thank you for you help

Comment: Why are so many people downvoting?

Comment: Question : Why use only arrow functions ? use them where you need them, not where they are complicating your code. Arrow functions are very useful when you have classes and define class methods where you need to access the `class` with `this`. Here, in your case, i don't see any reason why you should use them.

Comment: @MihaiT I wanted to move the initComplete() code into another function that is why

Comment: well..there are better ways to do that. just send `this` as an argument. and access it in your new function. for eg : `"initComplete": myFunction(this)` and then use it `function myFunction(elem) {  console.log(elem) }` will return the `#example`

Comment: @MihaiT do you always try to use normal functions as much as possible? is that good practice? I'm fairly new to arrow functions

Comment: as you may have read on the web, the main reason arrow functions are used is for the use of `this`. I, for example, use arrow function 90% of the time when working in React where i need to use `this` in reference to the `class` component. So the arrow functions can be used in object oriented programming, but also when you want to return something and write less code and you do not need the `this` keyword. eg : `const length = array.map(item=> item.length)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
       ....       
      "initComplete": function(oSettings) {
         $(this).on('click', "i.fa.fa-minus-square", function(e) {
           table.row( $(this).closest('tr') ).remove().draw();
         });
      ....
  });
```

Here, the first `this` is referenced to `#example` so replace it with it. The second `this` is referenced to `i.fa.fa-minus-square`, the element you bind the click on. So replace it accordingly.

```
   $(this).on('click', 'i.fa.fa-pencil-square', function(e){
        var rowData = table.row($(this).closest('tr')).data();
```

Here it's the same. First `this` is `#example` second is `i.fa.fa-pencil-square`.

And so on

Question : Why use only arrow functions ? use them where you need them, not where they are complicating your code. Arrow functions are very useful when you have classes and define class methods where you need to access the `class` with `this`. Here, in your case, i don't see any reason why you should use them.

If you want to use a separate function for the initComplete, you can pass `this` as an argument. for eg : `"initComplete": myFunction(this)` and then use it `function myFunction(elem) {  console.log(elem) }` will return the `#example`

Comment: this is correct but I had to use e.target for the onclick function because otherwise it would just bind to the same fa.fa-pencil-square

Comment: yes. that's a downside for not using `this` . But let me ask you something. Why use only arrow functions ? use them where you need them, not where they are complicating your code.

Comment: I used e.target instead. It works fine now. Thank you for you help

Answer (score 1):

In the event handler, replace `this` with `e.target` (which is the element that triggered the event, and the same as `this`):

```
table.row($(e.target).closest('tr')).remove().draw();
```

Comment: thank you for editing my question. e.target sounds good but how can I replace (this).on('click', "i.fa.fa-minus-square", function(e) {} without using this